# File Stream Encryption + Decryption Adding Random Data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, encryption, cryptography

I am currently developing a private cloud storage site using AWS S3 for personal use. The infrastructure is simple - upload files with my API, API will encrypt + upload to Amazon S3. You can also download it, where my API acts as a middleware to decrypt the file and stream it to my client. The issue is that random data is being added to the file when downloading, but it's different every time. Is this some sort of metadata? Let me show you what I'm talking about:

file.txt

```
Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet fugiat fatback ut flank dolor in ea, aute buffalo duis. T-bone occaecat sunt nisi commodo pig. Beef ullamco prosciutto irure cow dolore. Reprehenderit chicken ut, pork chop venison consectetur quis in. Ut pig duis aliqua.
```

file.txt.unec after encrypting, uploading, downloading, decrypting

```
l5T
 ��ĕ�]�'Q�Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet fugiat fatback ut flank dolor in ea, aute buffalo duis. T-bone occaecat sunt nisi commodo pig. Beef ullamco prosciutto irure cow dolore. Reprehenderit chicken ut, pork chop venison consectetur quis in. Ut pig duis aliqua.
```

I tried base64 encoding the file before uploading to see if there is any data loss, but it works exactly the same as above:

file.txt.base64

```
U3BpY3kgamFsYXBlbm8gYmFjb24gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3IgYW1ldCBmdWdpYXQgZmF0YmFjayB1dCBmbGFuayBkb2xvciBpbiBlYSwgYXV0ZSBidWZmYWxvIGR1aXMuIFQtYm9uZSBvY2NhZWNhdCBzdW50IG5pc2kgY29tbW9kbyBwaWcuIEJlZWYgdWxsYW1jbyBwcm9zY2l1dHRvIGlydXJlIGNvdyBkb2xvcmUuIFJlcHJlaGVuZGVyaXQgY2hpY2tlbiB1dCwgcG9yayBjaG9wIHZlbmlzb24gY29uc2VjdGV0dXIgcXVpcyBpbi4gVXQgcGlnIGR1aXMgYWxpcXVhLgo=
```

file.txt.base64.unec

```
���|ȱ�����j�bU3BpY3kgamFsYXBlbm8gYmFjb24gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3IgYW1ldCBmdWdpYXQgZmF0YmFjayB1dCBmbGFuayBkb2xvciBpbiBlYSwgYXV0ZSBidWZmYWxvIGR1aXMuIFQtYm9uZSBvY2NhZWNhdCBzdW50IG5pc2kgY29tbW9kbyBwaWcuIEJlZWYgdWxsYW1jbyBwcm9zY2l1dHRvIGlydXJlIGNvdyBkb2xvcmUuIFJlcHJlaGVuZGVyaXQgY2hpY2tlbiB1dCwgcG9yayBjaG9wIHZlbmlzb24gY29uc2VjdGV0dXIgcXVpcyBpbi4gVXQgcGlnIGR1aXMgYWxpcXVhLgo=
```

As you can see, the base 64 string is still preserved, just has some sort of leadin data. Here is my encryption/decryption logic:

encrypt.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const AppendInitVect = require('./appendInitVect');
const getCipherKey = require('./getCipherKey');

function encrypt({ file, secret }) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const initVect = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const CIPHER_KEY = getCipherKey(secret);
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.on('data',console.log)
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes256', CIPHER_KEY, initVect);
    const appendInitVect = new AppendInitVect(initVect);
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(file + ".enc"));
    var stream = readStream
      .pipe(cipher)
      .pipe(appendInitVect)
      .pipe(writeStream);
    stream.on('finish', resolve);
  })

}

module.exports = encrypt;
```

decrypt.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const uuid = require('uuid/v1');
const getCipherKey = require('./getCipherKey');


function decrypt({stream,res,secret}) {
  const initVect = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const CIPHER_KEY = getCipherKey(secret);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', CIPHER_KEY, initVect);
  var id = uuid();
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(id+'.unenc');
  return stream.pipe(decipher).pipe(writeStream);
}



module.exports = decrypt;
```

appendInitVect.js

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');

class AppendInitVect extends Transform {
  constructor(initVect, opts) {
    super(opts);
    this.initVect = initVect;
    this.appended = false;
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    if (!this.appended) {
      this.push(this.initVect);
      this.appended = true;
    }
    this.push(chunk);
    cb();
  }
}

module.exports = AppendInitVect;
```

getCipherKey.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = function (secret) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(secret).digest();
}
```

Is there something crazy I'm doing wrong here? If upload/download to S3 login is needed here I can provide that too. I have also tested upload/download WITHOUT encryption and it works perfectly with no extra data.

Comment: Just guessing if this line is the culprit `this.push(this.initVect);`

Comment: @HarryJoy Removing that line causes the outputted file to be: Ŕ�~��Q��h�M�r�acon ipsum dolor amet fugiat fatback ut flank dolor in ea, aute buffalo duis. T-bone occaecat sunt nisi commodo pig. Beef ullamco prosciutto irure cow dolore. Reprehenderit chicken ut, pork chop venison consectetur quis in. Ut pig duis aliqua.

Comment: You need to extract the IV and use it for decryption of the data *without* the IV.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bbstilson/a3a6c74fdc2a2519ab6ba59bcd06a1c4/raw/5a4be7823240af394842987dc1f53bfc2db67964/decrypt.js), which (apart from the uncompression) is essentially what you need and which is explained in more detail [here](https://medium.com/@brandonstilson/lets-encrypt-files-with-node-85037bea8c0e), Part 3: Decryption.